@SpringBootTest that asserts "Failed to load ApplicationContext"
I have introduced some validation code in the form of a @PostConstruct that checks a Spring Boot application's application.properties for mis-configuration. If an issue is detected, it throws an IllegalStateException and the application fails to start.
@PostConstruct
private void validate() {
    if (someConfig.isInvalid()) {
         throw new IllegalStateException("Config invalid");
    }
}

As expected / desired, when trying to start the application with some bad config, it fails to start with:
ava.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext for [WebMergedContextConfiguration@3df52a50 testClass ...

Is is possible to test this in a @SpringBootTest?
Something like
@TestPropertySource(
    properties = {
        "invalid-config=BAD"
    }
)
class FailureIntegrationTest {
    @Test
    public void givenBadConfig_whenApplicationStarts_thenFailToStart() {
        Assertions.fail("Application should not have started");
    }
}


Please add the stack trace and also add the code where you updated it.

@AnishB.There is no stack trace.
